# What is this symbol in Eagle and equivalent for altium

Tags: pcb, altium, eaglecad

I only use Altium Designer. Today I found an arduino due schematic for Eagle PCB Design Software and I saw a symbol I don't know.

What is it, and what is the equivalent in Altium Designer? Is it a directive>>PCB layout in Altium maybe?

[image]

Comment: I happen to have a copy of the DUE that I transferred to Altium in 2013.  Want a copy?  I remember their prints being a complete mess.

Comment: Actually, it's still listed here: [https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=146574.0](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=146574.0)

Comment: Oh gosh, Im creating all from from eagle file hahaha

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that those are testpoints.

On the schematic, I would use a single-pin connector symbol.  Altium may have a suitable schematic symbol in its libraries somewhere, but it may be easier to make your own symbol than finding something suitable in the libraries.

On the PCB, I would use a footprint consisting of a single pad of some convenient size.

You could, of course, simply ignore them, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have a footprint for test point :D

Answer (score 1):

They are test points connected to usb plug. Please look at the image.
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much friends